# ConfigServersInconsistent:How to correct the inconsistency?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, configuration

Detected that the one of the config servers is inconsistent with rest two, in a 3 config-server environment. But not sure how to set this right. I have gone through [mongodb config servers not in sync](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48232/mongodb-config-servers-not-in-sync) and found that one of the **chunks** collection has a different dbhash compared to the other two. Will a plain replacement of the shards collection on this configserver work? Else, what needs to be done?